# Kendo Grid/Detail Grid - How to access a dropdown correctly on the detail grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have a grid/detail grid set up. On the detail grid, I have a drop down list. The editor function for the drop down is:

```
function ActionTypeEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input id="ddlActionType" data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id"> data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" ').appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: GC.ViewModels.Config.AlertAction.actionTypeArray
    }).appendTo(container).data("kendoDropDownList").text(options.model.ActionTypeId);

var dropdownlist = $("#ddlActionType").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.value(options.model.ActionTypeId);
```

}

This works fine when I edit one row on a detail grid associated with the "parent" grid row. However, if I edit another detail row associated with another parent row BELOW the first, the next to last stamement
where I select the dropdown list always gets the first one on the page, rather than the one for the lower row. How do I get the correct drop
down list?

Answer (score 0):

Why, you use

```
var dropdownlist = $(container.find("#ddlActionType")).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

instead.

You're welcome!